# Angular angular-oauth2-oidc v15.0.0 client id not included in logout

Tags: angular, angular-oauth2-oidc

I have an application in angular (14.2.0), on logout I am calling `this.oidcSecurityService.logoffAndRevokeTokens()`

and see this logout request has only postLogoutRedirectUri in params, but not clientId also. ClientId in my case is required on outh server. In config I have both fields fill in.

```
export const httpLoaderFactory = (httpClient: HttpClient) => {
  const config$ = httpClient.get<any>( environment.auth ).pipe(
    map((customConfig: any) => {
      return {
        postLogoutRedirectUri: ...,
        clientId: ...,
```

Can you please point out the reason? On the end after logout I am receiving an empty main page and login flow is not triggered, but on refresh login flow is triggered normally.